# Google Sheets REGEXEXTRACT from Instagram

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm facing a particular challenge with regular expression.

I am populating a Google sheet with Google search results of Instagram post captions with the following repetitive pattern:

```
A |                          B                                  |    C   |    D
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 10.7k Likes, 1.7k Comments - @kristiannairn on Instagram... |        |
2 | 4219 Likes, 176 Comments - @djiglobal on Instagram...       |        |
3 | 1.1m Likes, 209k Comments - @kristiannairn on Instagram...  |        |
```

I'm trying unsuccessfully to find the right `REGEXEXTRACT` formula to extract the number of **Likes with decimals and the k/m designators** following it and without when it is not existent, to populate **Column C**, and then the `REGEXEXTRACT` formula to extract the number of **Comments with decimals and the k/m designators** following it and without when it is not existent, to populate **Column D**.

So far I was able to come up with this formula for **Column C** to extract the Likes:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B1,"(\.?\d*)\W?(?:Likes)")
```

However, it does not recognize decimals and does not fetch the k/m designators.

I have the same problem with the **Column D** comments formula I found:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B1,"(\.?\d*)\W?(?:Comments)")
```

Same here... it does not recognize decimals and does not fetch the k/m designators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA({
 REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "(.*) Like"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, ", (.*) Comm")}))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

For `Likes`, you may use

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?[km]?)\W*Likes\b
```

and for `Comments`,

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?[km]?)\W*Comments\b
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/kNTGBP/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/kNTGBP/1/). Proof:

[image]

**Details**

- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?[km]?)` - Group 1: 1+ digits followed with an optional sequence of `.` and 1+ digits and then an optional `k` or `m`
- `\W*` - 0+ non-word chars
- `Likes` - a word `Likes`
- `\b` - a word boundary.